reading an image with cv2.imread vs matplotlib.pyplot.imread
I am trying to read and show a photo,
it works when I use plt.imshow(..) and I know for sure that the photo and the path are ok.
when I try using cv2 it says the photo is a nonetype
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

img=cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\shayf\OneDrive\שולחן העבודה\Work\CV Course\OneDrive_1_12-4- 
2024\images\tulips.jpg')
plt.imshow(img[:,:,::-1])

I know plt is for RGB and cv2 is for BGR.
It doesn't work when I try to use cv2.imread either.
Can someone please help?
Thanks in advance!

maybe it's the hebrew letters, but am not sure. I remember opencv imread doesn't like special characters in their paths

Yes, it'll be because of the special letters

Try reading the file content to a byte array and use cv2.imdecode

known issue. opencv doesn't handle paths containing unicode.

that questions's answers also show better solutions (such as np.fromfile)

OpenCV has problems with non-ASCII filenames.
You can use standard Python read() or Pathlibto read the JPEG-encoded data, then OpenCV to decode from JPEG to Numpy array:
from pathlib import Path
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

# Read JPEG-encoded file as bytes
JPEG = Path('YOURIMAGE.jpg').read_bytes()

# Decode into Numpy array
im = cv.imdecode(np.frombuffer(JPEG, dtype=np.uint8), cv.IMREAD_COLOR)


I'll pick out any of the older questions to close this as a duplicate. I hope that agrees with you.
